# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer Exception

Tags: jax-rs

I am new to JAX-RS Annotations, When I try to run this I got an error like

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer,

Help me to resolve this issue and I added commons-logging 1.2 jar and jersey-bundle 1.18 jar.

index.html

```
<a href="rest/hello/javatpoint">Click Here</a>
```

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"   
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">  
    <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
        <init-param>  
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>  
            <param-value>com.javatpoint.rest</param-value>  
        </init-param>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

HelloService.java

```java
package com.javatpoint.rest; 

import javax.ws.rs.GET;  
import javax.ws.rs.Path;  
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;  
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;  

@Path("/hello")  
public class HelloService{  
    @GET  
    @Path("/{param}")  
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {  
        String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;  
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Also, this is because you are mixing Jersey 1.0 and 2.0. Use Jersey 2.x jars instead. Or see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this web.xml servlet directive - change necessary info:

```
<servlet> <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name> <!-- Define ServletContainer of Jersey --> <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> <!-- Define the package to search for classes --> <init-param> <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name> <param-value>com.javatpoint.rest</param-value> </init-param> <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> </servlet>
```